# Visual Studio extension not loading

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I'm using Visual Studio 2012. Recently I find extension for JS unit test doesn't load. I goto menu `Tools->Extensions abd Updates`, the extension's `Enable` button is disabled. I tried a few ways to fix this:

- Reinstall JS unit test extension
- Reinstall latest version of extension
- Repair Visual Studio

I almost try to reinstall Visual Studio. How to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible reason is, you are running Visual Studio as administrator, and the extension is installed by another user of this computer. For this case:

Goto menu `Tools->Options->Environment->Extensions and Updates`, check `Load per users extension when running as administrator`.